# Java Sockets Android - can read only on second access

Tags: java, android, sockets

i'm happy to ask my first android question now; I've got a slight problem while accessing a member variable of the following inner class named tcpIpClient. First, template gets instantiated in my MainActivity, which launches an instance of my connection class and the connection gets set. In The putMsg method in the template class then calls the following connect() method in connection class, which looks like this:

```
public class Connection {

TcpIpClient tcpClient;
private String ip;
private String pass;


public Connection(String ip, String pass) throws IOException{
    this.ip = ip;
    this.pass=pass;
    tcpClient = new TcpIpClient(ip, 9595);


}

public String connect(int type, String msg) throws IOException{
    switch(type) {

        case 1:tcpClient.connect(msg);break;
        case 2: //bluetClient.connect();break;
        case 3: //
    }
    return tcpClient.message;
}

class TcpIpClient {
    String ip;
    int port;
    String message="";

    public TcpIpClient(String ip, int port){
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;


    }
    void connect(String mess) throws IOException {

        final String messa = mess;
        Thread nwThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    resetMessage();

                    java.net.Socket socket = new java.net.Socket(ip, port); // verbindet sich mit Server
                    //socket.setSoTimeout(3000);

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);

                    pw.println(messa);
                    pw.flush();
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        tcpClient.message += br.readLine()+"\n";

                    }

                    is.close();
                    isr.close();

                    br.close();
                    socket.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

            }});
         nwThread.start();

    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    }


}
public String getMessage(){
    return tcpClient.getMessage();
}
public void resetMessage(){
    tcpClient.message=null;
}
```

}

Everything works fine, even Android Studio's debugger gives the result, which is the output of a programm launched within the server class through getRuntime().exec(), except for that the result of my method call to getMessage() in my MainActivity, despite containing the results of tcpClient.message, can't be passed to another method (e.g. Log.v or even displayed in a common alert dialog). It seems to make no difference, whether i switch the return type of connect() to void and return message using it, or leave its return type String. Again: even though the debugger sees the value of conn.tcpClient.message, and the method calls to Log.v or the alert dialog get the variable passed according to debugger, it just doesn't work - FOR THE FIRST TIME. The next time i launch the (or another) command through putMsg(), the result of the first method call to getRuntime()exec() on the server gets displayed (inside Log.V or the alert dialog). Someone please help me. I went through days debugging already, changing everything. Please let me know if you need additional information. Thank you very much in advance, Michael.

```
void putMsg(String msg){

    try{
        conn.connect(1, msg);
    }catch(IOException e){}

}
```

Comment: My solution was a workaround now. I just added a boolean right before "is.close();" and got the working example by accessing the response from the MainActivity class only after an endless while loop that simply checks for the state of the boolean variable if it has finished, which works pretty fine now. I guess that is not best practice, but at least it works. Thank you very much.